# Writing a piecewise linear function as a sum of ReLU functions

Tags: neural-network, activation-function

Suppose I have a piecewise linear function $f(x) = \sum^n_{i=1}a_i\phi_i(x)$, where $\{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is a finite dimension space of dimension $n-1$, in particular I am interested in the functions of the form:
$$  \phi_{j}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac{x-x_{j-1}}{h}, & \text { if } x_{j-1} \leq x \leq x_{j} \\ \frac{x_{j+1}-x}{h}, & \text { if } x_{j} \leq x \leq x_{j+1} \\ 0, & \text { otherwise }\end{array}\right.$$

Rough illustration: 
[image]

Now, suppose I am working with the ReLU activation function $\sigma(x)=max(0,x)$ and I am trying to find the coefficients $\alpha,W$ and biases $b$ such that the function $u_\theta(x) = \sum^n_{i=1} \alpha_i \sigma(w_ix+b_i)$ is exactly our function $f(x)$.

In other words, for a given piecewise linear function $f(x) = \sum^n_{i=1}a_i\phi_i(x)$, what are the coefficients $\alpha,W,b$ such that $\sum^n_{i=1}a_i\phi_i(x)=\sum^n_{i=1} \alpha_i \sigma(w_ix+b_i)$?

Comment: Welcome to Data Science SE. You cross-posted almost the same question on Math SE at [Finding the coefficients of a piecewise linear function in a different basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3599924/602049). This is generally frowned upon but if you do so then, at the minimum, please indicate this with a link to help minimize duplicated efforts.